# Placing many pins on a Google Map

Tags: javascript, performance, html5, google-maps

It's taking almost 2 minutes to load all the pins on this Google Maps API. Every time the page is loaded it sends a request for each location one by one. Can it do this all at the same time or preload the map beforehand? How can I make this load faster?

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['map'],
      // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
      // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
      'mapsApiKey': 'some api key'
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap () {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Address');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Marker')

      data.addRows([
        ['New York City NY, United States', 'New York',   'blue' ],
        ['Boston MA, United States',      'Boston',   'blue'],
        ['College Park MD, United States',    'College Park', 'blue' ],
        ['Washington DC, United States',    'Washington DC', 'green' ],
        ['Newark DE, United States',    'Newark', 'blue' ],
        ['St.Petersburg, Russia',    'St. Petersburg', 'blue' ],
        ['Moscow, Russia',    'Moscow', 'green' ],
        ['Philadelphia PA, United States',  'Philly',     'green'],
        ['Wilmington DE, United States',  'Wilmington',     'green'],
        ['Assateague Island MD, United States',    'Assateague Island', 'green'],
        ['Quebec, Canada',       'Quebec',    'blue' ],
        ['Montreal, Canada',       'Quebec',    'blue' ],
        ['Nome AL, United States',    'Nome', 'green'],
        ['Baltimore MD, United States',     'Baltimore',  'green' ],
        ['Miami FL, United States',        'Miami',     'green' ],
        ['Orlando FL, United States',        'Orlando',     'green' ],
        ['San Diego CA, United States',     'San Diego',  'green'], 
        ['Key West FL, United States',     'Key West',  'green'], 
        ['Dallas TX, United States',     'Dallas',  'green'], 
        ['Victoria, Canada',     'Victoria',  'green'], 
        ['Seattle WA, United States',     'Seattle',  'green'], 
        ['Cairo, Cairo Governorate, Egypt', 'Cairo', 'green'], 
        ['Luxor, Cairo Governorate, Egypt', 'Luxor', 'green'], 
        ['Quito, Ecuador', 'Quito', 'green'],
        ['Otavalo, Ecuador', 'Otavalo', 'green'],
        ['Papallacta, Ecuador', 'Papallacta', 'green'],
        ['Punta Ahuano, Ecuador', 'Punta Ahuano', 'green'],
        ['Banos, Ecuador', 'Banos', 'green'],
        ['San Juan Del Sur, Nicaragua', 'San Juan Del Sur', 'green'],
        ['Ometepe, Nicaragua', 'Ometepe', 'green'],
        ['Leon, Nicaragua', 'Leon', 'green'],
        ['Ometepe, Nicaragua', 'Ometepe', 'green'],
        ['Bangkok, Thailand', 'Bangkok', 'green'],
        ['Chiang Mai, Thailand', 'Chiang Mai', 'green'],
        ['Pai, Thailand', 'Pai', 'green'],
        ['Koh Tao, Thailand', 'Koh Tao', 'green'],
        ['Istanbul, Turkey', 'Istanbul', 'green'],
        ['Antalya, Turkey', 'Antalya', 'green'],
        ['Ankara, Turkey', 'Ankara', 'green'],
        ['Canakkale, Turkey', 'Canakkale', 'green'],
        ['Izmir, Turkey', 'Izmir', 'green'],
        ['Cappadocia, Turkey', 'Cappadocia', 'green'],
        ['Dubai, UAE', 'Dubai', 'green'],
        ['Abu Dabi, UAE', 'Abu Dabi', 'green'],
        ['Lisbon, Portugal', 'Lisbon', 'green'],
        ['Lagos, Portugal', 'Lagos', 'green'],
        ['Rome, Italy', 'Rome', 'green'],
        ['Venice, Italy', 'Venice', 'green'],
        ['Naples, Italy', 'Naples', 'green'],
        ['Pompeii, Italy', 'Pompeii', 'green'],
        ['Vienna, Austria', 'Vienna', 'green'],
        ['Prague, Czechia', 'Prague', 'green'],
        ['Budapest, Hungary', 'Budapest', 'green'],
        ['Jerusalem, Israel', 'Jerusalem', 'green'],
        ['Tel Aviv, Israel', 'Tel Aviv', 'green'],
        ['Rabat, Morocco', 'Rabat', 'green'],
        ['Casablanca, Morocco', 'Casablanca', 'green'],
        ['Fes, Morocco', 'Fes', 'green'],
        ['Marrakesh, Morocco', 'Marrakesh', 'green'],
        ['Honolulu HI, United States', 'Honolulu', 'green'],
        ['Maui HI, United States', 'Maui', 'green'],
        ['Oahu HI, United States', 'Oahu', 'green'],
        ['Dominican Republic', 'Dominican Republic', 'green'],
        ['Puerto Rico, United States', 'Puerto Rico', 'green'],
        ['Las Vegas NV, United States', 'Las Vegas', 'green'],
        ['Desert Island ME, United States', 'Desert Island', 'green'],
        ['Portland ME, United States', 'Portland', 'green'],
        ['Burlington VT, United States', 'Burlington', 'green'],
        ['New Mexico 597, Teec Nos Pos, AZ, United States', 'Four Corners Monument', 'green'],
        ['Bryce Canyon National Park Utah, United States', 'Bryce Canyon National Park', 'green'],
        ['Bermuda Triangle', 'Bermuda Triangle', 'green'],
      ]);
      var url = 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/48/';

      var options = {
        zoomLevel: 2,
        showTooltip: true,
        showInfoWindow: true,
        useMapTypeControl: true,
        icons: {
          blue: {
            normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Azure-icon.png',
            selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Right-Azure-icon.png'
          },
          green: {
            normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Chartreuse-icon.png',
            selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Right-Chartreuse-icon.png'
          },
          pink: {
            normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Pink-icon.png',
            selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Right-Pink-icon.png'
          }
        }
      };
      var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

      map.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map_div"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is taking so long because Google is geocoding each of your locations one by one. Geocoding takes a lot of time as the world is a very big place and you have a lot of locations.

You can save some load time by [geocoding in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878259/1444609) and passing in the latitude and the longitude in place of the location name. So for example, instead of

```
['New York City NY, United States', 'New York',   'blue' ],
```

You could provide the coordinates for NY...

```
[40.730610, -73.935242, 'New York',   'blue' ],
```

This should give you that boost you need.

Alternatively, instead of using charts, standard [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map) might be faster, or even [static maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/), which is focused on being fast.